# Unhandled Exception when using itoa

Tags: c, windows, debugging, error-handling, itoa

Below is a part of my code. I am not sure what is wrong with it because when I debug this code, I get a the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x60e8144c (msvcr90d.dll) in client0.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

This is somewhere in the line itoa.

**CODE:**

```
   int num =  LOWORD (lparam);
   char *number = NULL,*detail = NULL;
   (char*)itoa(num,number,10);
```

Comment: The runtime error says "I can't write to address 0x00000000". This should make you suspect that a write to a null pointer is taking place. You have such pointers in your program. You write to them. Hence the error message.

Comment: What about reading some documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is pointer and you haven't allocated memory for it. And then trying to write into it.

Update it to use array or allocate memory using `malloc`

```
int num =  LOWORD (lparam);
char number[20],*detail = NULL;
(char*)itoa(num,number,10);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a valid initialized pointer to `itoa()`.

Comment: Do you mean I have to initialize *number with some value first? :(

Comment: @AyeshaHassan No, `number` must point to a valid memory location where there is allocated memory.

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea now :)